# glob2rx, placing a wildcard in the middle of expression and specificying exeptions, r

Tags: r

I have am writing an R script that performs a function for all files in a series of subdirectories. I have ran into a problem where several files in these subdirectories are being recognized by my glob2rx function, and I need help refining my pattern so I can select the file I want.

Here is an example of my directory structure:

```
subdir1
   file1_aaa_111_subdir1.txt
   file1_bbb_111_subdir1.txt
   file1_aaa_subdir1.txt


subdir2
   file1_aaa_111_subdir2.txt
   file1_bbb_111_subdir2.txt
   file1_aaa_subdir2.txt
```

I want to select for the last file in each directory, although in my actual directory its position is varied. I want to use something like:

```
inFilePaths = list.files(path=".", pattern=glob2rx("*aaa*.txt"), full.names=TRUE)
```

but I dont get any files. In looking at this pattern, I would in theory get both the first and last file in each directory. Meaning I need to write an exception to exclude the aaa_111 files, and keep the aaa_subdir files.

There is a second option I have been thinking about, but lack the ability to realize. Notice the name of the subdirectory is at the end of each file name. Is it possible to extract the directory name, and then combine it with a glob2rx pattern, and then directly specify which file I want? Like this:

```
#list all the subdirectories
subDirsPaths = list.dirs(path=".", full.names=TRUE)

#perform a function on these directories one by one    
  for (subDirsPath in subDirsPaths){
#make the subdirectory the working directory 
  setwd("/home/phil/Desktop/working")
  setwd(paste(subDirsPath, sep=""))

  # get the working directory name, and trim the "./" from it
  directory <- gsub("./", "", paste(subDirsPath, sep=""))

# attempt to the get the desired file by pasting the directory name into the glob2rx funtion 
  inFilePaths = list.files(path=".", pattern=glob2rx("*aaa_", print(directory,".txt")), full.names=TRUE)
  for (inFilePath in inFilePaths)
  {
    inFileData <- read_tsv(inFilePath, col_names=TRUE)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some modification the second option worked well. I ended up using paste in combination with print as follows:

```
inFilePaths = list.files(path=".", pattern=glob2rx(print(paste("*", "aaa_", directory, ".txt", sep=""))), full.names=TRUE)
```

The paste function combined the text into a single string, which also preserved the wildcard. The print function added this to the list.files function as the glob2rx pattern.

While this doesn't allow me to place a wild card in the middle of an expression, which I believe is done use an escape character, and it doesn't address the need to place exceptions on the wild card, it works for my purposes.

I hope this helps others in my position.